# Crawler server side

Tags: linux, postgresql, server-side, web-crawler

I have a question about a particular server side functionality.

I have a server (Linux) with a PostgreSQL database (server side developed in python).
I would like to create a system that at regular intervals (once a day .. maybe overnight) deletes all expired information from database.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Is correct to call this system as 'crawler'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [crontab](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/crontab.5.php) for the scheduling purposes. It is the de facto standard for scheduling in Linux environments and it is also very flexible.

As for the deletion.. depending on your exact needs I think stored procedures might be the way to go. PostgreSQL is modular, so you can use its built-in scripting language ([PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql.html)), but you can use Python, C, Tcl and the other supported languages too.

To execute stored procedures on the server from the console you can use [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) which is the console based client for postgres-based systems. It is capable to run user commands given as parameters or complete scripts from a file without user interaction.

I think "Crawler" is used for applications which retrieve data in an automatic manner and since you are going to delete them, this might not be the best way to call it.

To sum it up: create a stored procedure to perform your data maintenance (if this can be achieved with SQL commands only then you don't even have to learn PL/pgSQL in depth) then call psql with the correct parameters in your crontab to run it automatically.